# NLog weirdness - extra fields displayed

Tags: c#, nlog

I use NLog for debugging/tracing in my app. What's happening is that I am seeing some extra stuff in the output. This is C#/VisualStudio on the Mac, targeting iOS.

Here is an example...
I'm using a target of type "Debugger", and my layout line is:

```xml
<layout="${time} ${level} ${callsite}:${callsite-linenumber} ${message}"/>
```

The call to the logger is:

```
log.Debug("Added New Key. Code = {0}", code);
```

And the output is:

```
AppleLibrary.PasswordMgr: 16:04:36.4064 Debug 
AppleLibrary.PasswordMgr.SavePassword:55 Added New Key. Code = -34018
```

Every debug line starts with `<logger name>:`

Its even worse when I use a target type of "Console" with exactly the same layout. A call like this:

```
log.Debug("Started Application");
```

ends up with this:

```
2017-06-14 16:04:23.673 MyApp.iOS[11942:6245589] 16:04:23.6374 Debug MyApp.iOS.Application.Main:14 Started Application
```

in this case every line starts with: `2017-06-14 16:04:23.673 MyApp.iOS[11942:6245589]`, which looks like the long date, logger name and thread/tick information.

Note that this *does not happen* with my file target, even though it uses exactly the same layout! The above call shows this in the logfile.txt:

```
16:04:23.6374 Debug MyApp.iOS.Application.Main:14 Started Application
```

Which is exactly what I want.

Here is my NLog.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throwExceptions="true">
    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" 
            xsi:type="File" 
            header="############STARTING RUN ${date} ${time}"
            archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
            maxArchiveFiles="5"
            fileName="/Users/Paul/Dev/MyApp/MyApp.iOS/logfile.txt" 
            layout="${time} ${level} ${callsite}:${callsite-linenumber} ${message}"/>
        <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" 
            layout="${time} ${level} ${callsite}:${callsite-linenumber} ${message}"/>
        <target name="debugger" 
            xsi:type="Debugger" 
            layout="${time} ${level} ${callsite}:${callsite-linenumber} ${message}"/>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
        <logger name="CoreLibrary.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugger" enabled="false" />
        <logger name="AppleLibrary.*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="debugger" />
        <logger name="MyApp.iOS.*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />

    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I'd appreciate any pointers as to what I'm misunderstanding here.
Thanks.
Paul.

Comment: are you sure you're looking to the correct nlog.config? (maybe there is on in your bin folder)

Comment: Yeah... I thought that might be an issue too. So I added a single letter to the NLog.config and it appears in the output (changed "${time}" to "${time}T", and it appeared). So I'm very sure its the right one.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is *another* layout that is being applied for each target type - because each target has a specific set of extra data that is being added. But I can't find any mention of it.

Comment: It's only on the debugger target isn't?